# Worklight adapter: basic authentication. How can I set that all my adapters send the activeUser credentials in header of every procedure?

Tags: authorization, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, user-identification

I have a login page in Worklight that sets the active user on the worklight server.
This sets a userIdentity. In this userIdentity I save an encrypted string of 'username:password'.

Every time an adapterprocedure is called it tests if a user is logged in.
When he is logged in, the procedure is called.

In the back-end I use basic authentication for every REST call.
So I need in every call's header ->

```
    Authorization: Basic  encrypted(username:password)
```

When I mock this, everything works. Example ->

```
    var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    path : path,
     headers:{
            Authorization: "Basic "+"dGVzdDp0ZXN0"
        }
```

I need to set, that everytime a procedure is called, this 'username:password' is the username:password from the userIdentity of the user that is logged in in the worklightserver.

How can I do this?

---

[Authorizing HTTP Adapter in IBM Worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921978/authorizing-http-adapter-in-ibm-worklight)

Here they use $( username ), but I don't know where the $ sign is referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is the best way, but it works for me...

wheb setting a userIdentity i added a loginString in the user object.
this object contains a var credentials that i initiated in the login-adapter.

loginstring = encode.encode_base64(user:pass);

userIdentity = {

```
    userID:"01",
    displayName: "name",
    credentials:loginstring, 
    teacherId:"212",
```

}

WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);

Then in the adapter you can reach the userIdentity-object:

function get() {

```
var user = WL.Server.getActiveUser("AuthRealm");
var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    headers:{
        Authorization: "Basic " + user.credentials
    },
    path : 'path',
};
```

return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

Answer (score 0):

In your connection policy, all you need is:

```
        <authentication>
            <basic/>
        </authentication>
```

Then for each of your procedures, use:

```
<procedure name="getFeed" connectAs="endUser"/>
```

You only need the serverIdentity if you are using connectAs="server"

Comment: This way the userIdentity has to have a username and password?

Comment: You indicated that you wanted back end authentication based on the userid/password of the logged in user, not a fixed server identity.  You only need to configure a userid/password if you want to use a single server identity for all calls.  For connectAs="endUser" to work with basic auth, the mobile devices need to log into worklight with a userid/password.  What Login Module are you using?

Comment: We are using nonValidatingLoginModule. What exact parameters does the userIdentity has to have? Will username:"test", password:"test" in the userIdentity object work for basic authentication that needs "test" "test" to log in?

Comment: whatever username and password provided by the mobile device at login will be used in the basic auth header.  you shouldn't have to do anything other than protect the adapter procedures (define a security test for the procedures) and it should all just work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the login?

Comment: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/08_02_Form_based_authentication.pdf