# How to enter user credentials when calling password protected URL from a worklight adapter?

Tags: rest, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I want to call a rest service via http adapter. I do a get request to the url of the rest service but it is in a password protected domain. (if i try to access the url from browser it pops up a window for username and password.) How can i pass these credentials along with my get request? do i have to make a post request before that?

Comment: Maybe this will provide some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700910/attaching-cookie-to-worklight-adapter-response-header

Comment: The two answers in this question might also shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921978/authorizing-http-adapter-in-ibm-worklight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the  element of the HTTP adapter.

```
<authentication>
  <basic/>
    <serverIdentity>
      <username> ${user} </username>
      <password> ${password} </password>
   </serverIdentity>
</authentication>
```

It will pass the network credential while accessing the service url.